# Regexp matching time ranges

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression for parsing and validation of time ranges in Javascript. Keep in mind that I am simply looking to parse correctly structured strings of characters. The validation logic regarding the time ranges is made afterward

Requirements:

1. Time elements are expressed always in 24 hour and should be of (HH:mm)
   format.
2. Time range is defined as 2 time elements separated by a dash
3. String should at least have one timerange or more separated by comma
4. Matching pattern should tolerate spaces between elements
5. The validated string should either match as a whole or completely fail to match

What I came up is the following:

```
/((?:[01]\d:[0-5][0-9]|2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9])(?:\s?)-(?:\s?)(?:[01]\d:[0-5][0-9]|2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9])(?:\s?,\s?)?)/g
```

which seems to satisfy all the rules apart from rule 5. ie. if incorrect characters exist they simply not match but the expression does not fail as a whole

is there any way to embed rule 5 inside this regex?

Comment: can't you just slam in `^` and `$` and then use `/.../.test(str)`?

Comment: 11:34-12:34,18:00-20:00 should be a valid string and produce 2 matches ['11:34-12:34', '18:00-20:00']

Comment: And what are invalid strings?

Comment: strings that are not one or more comma seperated timeranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the anchors to mark start and end of string:

`^((?:[01]\d:[0-5][0-9]|2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9])(?:\s?)-(?:\s?)(?:[01]\d:[0-5][0-9]|2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9])(?:\s?,\s?)?)+$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZ3cZ5/2))

Then, grab the whole match, and then split by `,`.

Comment: 11:34-12:34,18:00-20:00 should be a valid string and produce 2 matches which in your demo it does not

Comment: Demo here `https://regex101.com/r/jZ3cZ5/2` can match the whole string, but the match is only 1, and I suggest to just split the string by `,` to obtain an array (if necessary).

Comment: the match is only one and the matched string is only the last time range. what I am looking for is to obtain an array with each time range as a element inside that array and if the string is invalid to obtain an empty array. I realize this could be accomplished with string functions. I am just looking of accomplishing this inside a single regex

Comment: It is just not possible to do with just regex, you will have to add a function. Also, the whole string matches (see, it is highlighted as a whole), and the last group is only shown on the right because it has been re-written (due to the `+` quantifier).